# Ember Ajax call not firing success or error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js, handlebars.js

This is a method in my ASP MVC 4 `App.js` file. Right now I'm trying just to get this method to contact the controller and bring some data back to the `success` function.

While I can see the breakpoint on the controller fire and therefore the Ember app is talking to the "server", none of the `console.log`'s in the `success` or `error` execute. The `console.log("inside all function")` statement does work, however, so I know I am in the `all` method.

This is my first attempt at using Ember, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've run the Ajax call manually in the browser console and am still not getting a response. Neither of the `console.log` statements in the success or error function are being called. Anyone see why that could be the case?

**App.js**

```
App.Store.reopenClass({
    all: function () {
        console.log("inside all function");
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: { id: '1' },
            url: '/Agent/GetAgentData',
            sucess: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
    public JsonResult GetAgentData(string Id)
    {
        Id = "0707090011";
        AgentDataClient agtData = new AgentDataClient();
        CompleteAgent completeAgent = agtData.NewCompleteAgent();
        BasicData basics = agtData.GetBasics(Id);
        completeAgent.Basics = basics;
        agtData.Close();

        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = "REQUEST",
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

Comment: Ember should have no influence here. Have you tried to do the ajax manually in your browser console and see wether you see log ouput? And regarding how to perform an ajax call in ember properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608431/ajax-promise-without-ember-data/15611355#15611355

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that. I still did not see the `console.log`'s that I was expecting.

Comment: If i am doing the call in the console here on stackoverflow, i am seeing the error message along with "GET http://stackoverflow.com/Agent/GetAgentData?id=1&_=1377023636923 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: That's weird, I get the same thing too. Do you see anything wrong with the controller method?

Comment: No idea. I am not a C# guy :-) But i looks basically fine to me.

Comment: is it a typo, or is your `success` method wrongly spelled? It should be `success` rather than `sucess`