# Emberjs template not binding to restful data

Tags: javascript, rest, templates, ember.js, binding

Got this route to get the data from a restful service

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({rootElement: '#planner'});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend();
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('home');
});
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return Ember.$.getJSON('/api/get-planner/');
    }
});
```

And template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    {{name}}
</script>
```

Somehow the value of name is not displayed. I can confirm the api is returning correct json data.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608431/ajax-promise-without-ember-data/15611355#15611355 to learn how to properly work with Ajax and Ember.

Comment: And actually your template should probably named home like your Route.

Comment: sorry about the template name, yes it's "home" I just copied the wrong one.

Comment: the link is so different to what I read here http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/ I am growing grey hair here, the documentation sucks arse!

Comment: The documentation shows a very basic approach here. A more advanced guide will be merged soon. Go with the approach i linked or put up a fiddle and we can work on it together.

Comment: Are you sure that you entered your home route? Put a test string into your home template to verify.

Comment: I am very sure I am at the home view, I just copied another view here by mistake

Comment: Put in a test string to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember-Data expects the JSON like this:

```
{
    planner: {
        name: 'Test'
        // your data
    }
}
```

So if your API returns this JSON:

```
{
    name: 'Test'
}
```

It won't work.
I would suggest to use Ember-Model instead (https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model), since it is more stable and allows you to customize the behavior of the REST adapter.

Your code might look like this:

```
 App.PlannerModel = Ember.Model.extend({
     name: Ember.attr(),
     // see the documentation of ember-model for this
 });

 App.PlannerModel.url = '/api/get-planner/';
 App.PlannerModel.adapter = Ember.RESTAdapter.create();

 App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
       return App.PlannerModel.find();
   }
});
```

If you want to take this approach, make sure not to include Ember-Data and use Ember-Model instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using that but somehow it appends '.json' to the end of the url and I have looked at the code doesn't seem to be able to change that.

Comment: Yes you can. Open ember-model.js, replace '.json' to ''.

Comment: :/ that's not very good then, for breaking upgradability, plus this doesn't work well with django rest framework.

Comment: So does ember and ember-data, right? They are still fast moving targets, we can't upgrade without breaking our existing code. The only solution is to stick with a version that **just works**, at least for now.