# How do I adapt to slow-loading highcharts in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts

I have an EmberJS route that, depending on various options, loads anywhere from 1-20 HighCharts into a single template. I'm currently using `Ember.RSVP.hash` with a AJAX-loading promise for each chart. My route more or less looks like:

```
model: function () {
    var promises = {};
    // forEach chart I wish to create (one promise per chart):
        promises[chartId] = Ember.$.getJSON(urlForChart).then(function (response) {
            // do some post-processing here
        });
    return Ember.RSVP.hash(promises);
}
```

The problem here is, the AJAX call may take awhile, especially if a lot of charts, and `Ember.RSVP.hash` waits for all promises to complete before rendering, so I'm stuck seeing my `loading.hbs` template for possibly awhile.

So is it possible to restructure my route / application so that instead of waiting for all promises to complete before rendering, that each chart will render as they complete? Is this even possible?

Or would it be better to initially render all the HighCharts with no data and then fetch each datasource individually afterwards (basically lazy-loading)? If so, how would I go about that in HighCharts/EmberJS?

BTW, I'm using `Ember 1.13.11` and `ember-cli-highcharts`, if that matters.

Comment: You could move each chart into component and do loading there. They would also need to take care of loading state and show it but that should not be problem.

Comment: My concern is, isn't loading data in a component anti-pattern in EmberJS?

Comment: I think its justifiable for your problem. Other think you could do is move loading code into setupController. That way you would skip waiting for promise to resolve.

Comment: Okay, I'll research loading in components. But can you provide an example of how I would move the loading code into setupController()?

Comment: Is it required to use promises, because you can try to call each $.ajax() asychchronised like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608431/ajax-promise-without-ember-data

Comment: Sebastian, no, it's not required to use promises, and I didn't quite realize I could've not used them. I ended up combining the answer in your link with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move promise into [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) to skip waiting for promise to resolve.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController(controller) {
    const promises = {};
    promises[0] = Ember.$.getJSON('example.com').then(response => {
      // do some post-processing here
    });
    this._super(controller, promises);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something very similar. In the route, I set up all the necessary data I need to make my REST call as well as render an empty div for each chart. And then in setupController, I did a simple for loop , firing off Ember.$.getJSON and sending the results to the controller as they finish asynchronously. Works like a charm!